# How to display 3 random numbers and time intervals together

Tags: angularjs

My task is to generate 3 random numbers from 1 to 100. Each one needs to be generated in 2-5 seconds.

Each number (together with the number of seconds in which it was generated) should appear on the screen as soon as it was generated. So, one by one (not all at the same time) the numbers should appear on the screen.

I managed to get the three random numbers on the screen, but I am not able to get the number of seconds appear on the screen together with the respective number.

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="Lotery">
      <div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Three random numbers from {{ bottomNumber }} to {{ topNumber }}<small> (each in {{ minSeconds }} - {{ maxSeconds }} seconds)</small></h1>
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="firePromise()">Click to get the numbers</button>
            <span ng-repeat="nr in resultNumbers track by $index">
              <h1>{{ nr }} </h1>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>


angular.module('Lotery',[]);

angular.module('Lotery').controller('MainController', function($scope, $q) {

    $scope.topNumber = 100;
    $scope.bottomNumber = 1;
    $scope.maxSeconds = 5;
    $scope.minSeconds = 2;

    function getNumber(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        setTimeout(function(){
            $scope.randomNumber = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( $scope.topNumber - $scope.bottomNumber + 1 )) + $scope.bottomNumber;    
            $scope.seconds = 1000 * Math.floor( Math.random() * ( $scope.maxSeconds - $scope.minSeconds + 1 )) + $scope.minSeconds;
            if(angular.isNumber($scope.randomNumber)){
                deferred.resolve($scope.randomNumber);
            } else {
                deffered.reject('Error');
            } 
        }, $scope.seconds);

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    $scope.firePromise = function(){
        $scope.resultNumbers = [];

        var promise = getNumber();

        promise.then(function(success){
            $scope.resultNumbers.push(success);
            return getNumber();
        }).then(function(success){
            $scope.resultNumbers.push(success);
            return getNumber();
        }).then(function(success){
            $scope.resultNumbers.push(success);
        });
    };

});
```

See my pen: http://codepen.io/M4i4/pen/EjyMdY

Comment: Off topic: "Lottery"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming your logic for the `seconds` is correct**, how about just resolve an object from the `getNumber()` function instead of simply the number, like:

```
deferred.resolve({ number: $scope.randomNumber, seconds: $scope.seconds / 1000 });
```

And then in your markup:

```
<span ng-repeat="nr in resultNumbers track by $index">
    <h1>{{ nr.number }} - {{ nr.seconds }}</h1>        
</span>
```

Your updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqrJZB)

That said, something the logic doesn't seem right.

Comment: You were right about the logic for the seconds. Two brackets were missing. So, not like that: $scope.seconds = 1000 * Math.floor( Math.random() * ( $scope.maxSeconds - $scope.minSeconds + 1 )) + $scope.minSeconds; but like that: $scope.seconds = 1000 * (Math.floor( Math.random() * ( $scope.maxSeconds - $scope.minSeconds + 1 )) + $scope.minSeconds);